# Derivatives Problem: Why is second term's coefficient less than zero?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Problem:

> If $f(x)=cx^2+dx+e$ for the function shown in the graph, then what values can $c$, $d$, and $e$ take on? [image]

The answer is $c<0$, $d<0$, $e>0$. I just don't understand why $d<0$. Since the slope of $f(x)$ is always negative, $f'(x)<0$ and since $f'(x)=(2c)x+d$, $(2c)x+d<0$. Since $c<0$, let's choose $c=-1$, and let's choose $x=3$. $(2)(-1)(3)+d<0$ which leads to $-6+d<0$ which leads to $d<6$. And the maximum value (in this case 6) of this open inequality can change based on what $c$ and $x$ values are chosen. So where am I wrong?

Comment: Well, if $x=0$, then $f(0)=e$. That's the y-intersect of your function and according to the picture it's a positive number. So, $e$ has got to be positive.

Comment: $d=f'(0)$......

Comment: $e > 0$, as the $y$-intercept is greater than $0$.

Comment: "Since the slope of $f(x)$ is always negative" - it's negative in the part shown in the picture, but that doesn't mean it's always negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note $c$ and $d$ are fixed values. From the diagram,

$$f'(x) = (2c)x + d \lt 0 \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

for all $x \ge 0$, as well as some $x \lt 0$ (in particular to just before the vertex at $x = \frac{-d}{2c}$). What you've shown is that $d \lt 6$ when checking at $x = 3$ with $c = -1$. However, $d$ must **also** satisfy the inequality \eqref{eq1} for all $x$ where $f'(x) \lt 0$, i.e., for $x \gt \frac{-d}{2c}$, with this including $x = 0$. As pointed out in another answer, at $x = 0$, you get $f'(0) = d$, so $d \lt 0$, regardless of the value of $c$. This is still consistent with your determination of $d \lt 6$ (with $c = -1$), but it's just more stringent.

Comment: Is the (1) a link?

Comment: @user532874 Yes, it's a link to the one equation I've provided which has (1) at the right. Using a link is not really needed here as there is only one equation, but I have a habit of always setting up & referencing my equations that way. Note this can be possibly somewhat useful if there is a long answer with many equations and I'm referencing an early equation near the bottom of the answer. P.S., I hope I've explained, to your satisfaction, why what you tried with $d$ didn't work properly.

Comment: Sorry Im still confused, what do you mean by $d$ must satisfy the inequality for all x-values? If $c$ is $-1$ and as $x$ decreases, $k$ decreases for $d<k$. So the only d-value that satisfies the inequality for all x-values is negative infinity which makes no sense.

Comment: @user532874 I only stated $d$ must satisfy the inequality for all $x \ge 0$, as well as some $x \lt 0$ (just to the vertex at $\frac{-d}{2c}$). I'm not sure what $k$ is which you're referring to. As for $c = -1$, the inequality becomes $-2x + d \lt 0$. If you mean $k = 2x$, so $d \lt k$, then note $k = 0$ at $x = 0$, so $d \lt 0$ there as stated. However, the inequality doesn't hold for all $x$, with it becoming $0$ at the vertex ($\frac{d}{2}$ for $c = -1$), so you can't keep decreasing $x$ to negative infinity.

Comment: @user532874 The $c$, $d$, $e$ must be consistent with the diagram you're provided with. You have, along with answers here, determined certain values & inequalities which $c$, $d$ & $e$ **must** satisfy. Any values of $c$, $d$ and/or $e$ that you chose which don't satisfy at least one of these conditions can't be a valid set of values. If you choose $c = -1$, then at $x = 3$, you've determined $d \lt 6$. This limits the possible choices for $d$, but it doesn't mean any $d$ which satisfies this inequality is valid, as it has to satisfy all of the conditions. ...

Comment: @user532874  As you ask, $d = 5$ is **not** a valid choice as the inequality shows at $x=0$ that $d \lt 0$. Note not necessarily any $d \lt 0$ will necessarily be valid, but as there are no values of $x$ or $y$ provided in the graph, you can't determine the scales being used, so you can't really calculate any specific values of $c$, $d$ and/or $e$. Thus, with the information you've been given, you really can't be too much more specific than $d \lt 0$. Fortunately, the question just wants you to determine some rough bounds, i.e., positive or negative, which you can do with the info you have.

Comment: So based on what you said, let's say the x-coordinate of the vertex is $-3$. Therefore, $f'(x)<0$ is true for all $x>-3$. If $c=-1$, we can simplify $f'(x)<0$ as $d<2x$. If $x=3$, we get $d<6$, if $x=2$, we get $d<4$, if $x=1$, we get $d<2$, if $x=-2.9$, we get $d<-5.8$, etc. So we can infinitely limit the choices of $d$ because we can get infinitely close to $-3$. We don't really know what values $d$ is allowed to take on.

Comment: @user532874 If the $x$-coordinate of the vertex is $-3$, which is given by $-\frac{d}{2c}$, plus you have $c = -1$, then $-3 = -\frac{d}{2c} = -\frac{d}{2(-1)} = \frac{d}{2} \implies d = -6$. In this case, with the information given, there are no other choices for $d$. Of course, $-6 \lt -5.8$, and $-6 \lt 2x$ for any $x \gt -3$, so there's no inconsistency.

Comment: The inconsistency here though is that if $d<0$, then I'm allowed to choose $d=-1$. But in the scenario I made up, at $x=-2.9$, $d<-5.8$. Since $-1<-5.8$ is false, $d<0$ is not true.

Comment: @user532874 No, you're not necessarily allowed to choose $d = -1$ just because you know $d \lt 0$. The value of $d$ **must** be consistent with whatever information you have. The more details you have, the generally more restrictive you can be. In the original problem, you only have the graph, so you can only have more general constraints. In your earlier example where you've the vertex $x$-coordinate & choose $c = -1$, then there's only one value of $d$, i.e., $d = -6$, which satisfies $-3 = -\frac{d}{2c}$, plus it also satisfies all of the other known constraints, including of $d \lt 0$.

Comment: @user532874 In case you're still unsure, here's a visual concept. You initially have only a very fuzzy view, e.g., with the graph, the $x$ & $y$ intercepts could be a tiny fraction of $1$, or in the many trillions. You don't know. Thus, you only have very fuzzy type ideas of the $c,d,e$, i.e., $c \lt 0$, $d \lt 0$, $e \gt 0$, but have vertex $x$-coordinate of $-\frac{d}{2c}$. You don't know more than this for now. As you get more info, the picture becomes more in focus, so you can further restrict values, even perhaps giving them exactly, e.g., above has only $d=-6$ meeting all constraints.

Comment: I think I got it. We have no clue what $\frac{-d}{2c}$ is but we do know it's negative. Therefore, the smallest x-value we can plug into $f'(x)<0$ is $0$ (if we plug in a negative number, there's a chance that this number is to the left of the vertex). $c<0$ but it doesn't matter what the value of $c$ is because for any value of $c$, $d<0$. Now, if we **start assuming values**, like saying that the x-coordinate of the vertex is $-3$, $x=-2.9$,  and $c=-1$, which yields $d<-5.8$, the difference between $d<-5.8$ and $d<0$ is that $d<-5.8$ **may** be true but $d<0$ **is** true.

Comment: Not all inequalities are treated in equal regard

Comment: @user532874 I think you've basically got it now. However, at the end, I want to ensure I understand. With the vertex at $-3$ & $c = -1$, then $d = -6$, due to the $-3=-\frac{d}{2c}$. So both $d \lt -5.8$ & $d \lt 0$ are true. However, with other values of $c$ and/or the vertex $x$-coordinate, then $d \lt 5.8$ may only be true, but $d \lt 0$ is always true. I believe this is what you were getting at. As for not treating all inequalities in equal regard, keep in mind an inequality *only* says a value is in a given range, not that any value in the range is necessarily correct. Do this make sense?

Comment: That makes sense thank you

Answer (score 3):

The $x$-coordinate ( $\frac{-d}{2c}$ ) of the parabola vertex must be negative (to the left of the y-axis).

We know $c$ must be negative, because the parabola opens downwards.

So $d$ must be negative.

Comment: That makes sense to me, but where in my method did I go wrong?

Comment: I like to prove why wrong methods are wrong even if I can already find the answer a certain way (the way you just showed)

Answer (score 2):

$$f'(x)=2cx+d \implies f'(0)=d.$$
The slope at $x=0$ is negative, therefore $d<0$.

Comment: I understand what you did but why can't I choose $x=3$ or any $x$ value?

Comment: $d$ is a constant and this answer shows that $d$ is always negative. So, it's always a negative number. It has nothing to do with what values $x$ can take. $d$ is not going to be affected by it. It's a fixed number.

Answer (score 1):

No, for a quadratic polynomial, the slope  doesn't have a constant sign (otherwise, the polynomial wouldn't have an extremum).

If $c<0$, you can see on the graph that the parabola  has a maximum obtained at a point with a negative abscissa. As this maximum is obtained at $x=-\frac d{2c}$ (result from high school), what can you conclude for $d$?

Comment: $x$ coordinate of vertex has to be negative so $d<0$. But I still don't get where I went wrong in my method.

Comment: There's nothing really wrong. Simply you didn't the tightest possible bound for $d$ (taking the figure into account).

Answer (score 0):

> If $f(x)=cx^2+dx+e$ for the function shown in the graph, then what values can $c$, $d$, and $e$ take on?

Note: $c<0$, because the branches of the parabola open down. $e>0$, because $f(0)=e>0$.

> Since the slope of $f(x)$ is always negative, $f'(x)<0$ and since $f'(x)=(2c)x+d$, $(2c)x+d<0$.

No, the slope of $f(x)$ is not always negative, but:
$$\begin{cases}f'(x)>0, x<-\frac{d}{2c}\\ 
f'(x)<0,x>-\frac{d}{2c}\end{cases}$$
where $x=-\frac{d}{2c}$ is the $x$-coordinate of the vertex.

> Since $c<0$, let's choose $c=−1$, and let's choose $x=3$. $(2)(−1)(3)+d<0$ which leads to $−6+d<0$ which leads to $d<6$. And the maximum value (in this case 6) of this open inequality can change based on what $c$ and $x$ values are chosen. So where am I wrong?

If $c=-1,x=3$, then $f'(x)<0\iff x>-\frac{d}{2c} \Rightarrow 3>\frac{d}{2} \iff d<6$ is necessary, but not sufficient condition for the given parabola. Why? Because, from the graph it is visible that the vertex is on the left of origin (i.e. $x<0$). So, the vertex must be $x=-\frac{d}{2c}=\frac{d}{2}<0 \Rightarrow d<0$, which is the sufficient condition.